# User error message showing up all of the time

Tags: php, if-statement, authentication, system

This code is trying to validate whether a link has been entered into the browser, however, the warning message `Please enter the URL to clone` is still showing up on the top of the page even when it is not required. Can anybody suggest a way of it not showing up? I have attached my code below.

```
$posted_radio = (isset($_POST['git']) ? $_POST['git'] : null);
$posted_url = (isset($_POST['clone-url']) ? $_POST['clone-url'] : null);

if($posted_radio == "pull"){
    echo "This would cause a git pull";
}

if (!empty($posted_url)){
    echo "<p>This would post: </p><code>git clone"." ".$posted_url."</code>";
}else{
    echo "Please enter a URL to clone";
}


?>

<form method="POST" action="index.php">

    <input type="radio" name="git" value="clone" id="clone"><label>Clone</label><br>
    <label class="clone-url">Clone URL:</label><input type="url" name="clone-url" class="clone-url"><br>
    <input type="radio" name="git" value="pull"><label>Git Pull</label><br>

    <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: sure you're getting anything for that field? Does it show up in `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: That's what I got from doing a `var_dump($_POST)`: `array (size=2)
  'clone-url' => string '' (length=0)
  'git' => string 'pull' (length=4)`

Comment: there you go. it's an empty string, which in PHP counts as `empty()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your comment on the question, it seems `$post_url` is empty. You're not checking if `$post_url` is empty. Change your code to:

```
$posted_radio = (isset($_POST['git']) ? $_POST['git'] : null);
$posted_url = (isset($_POST['clone-url']) ? $_POST['clone-url'] : null);

if($posted_radio == "pull" && !empty($posted_url) ){
    echo "This would cause a git pull";
}

if (!empty($posted_url)){ //if url is not empty, print success
    echo "<p>This would post: </p><code>git clone"." ".$posted_url."</code>";
}elseif(!is_null($posted_url)){ //if url is not null, print error
    echo "Please enter a URL to clone";
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The `Please enter a URL to clone` message is still there

Answer (score 0):

As Marc B. pointed out, `$_POST['clone-url']` contains an empty string `''`.

Change this:

```
$posted_url = (isset($_POST['clone-url']) ? $_POST['clone-url'] : null);
```

to this:

```
$posted_url = (isset($_POST['clone-url']) && trim($_POST['clone-url']) !== '') ? $_POST['clone-url'] : null);
```

Comment: I have an error: `SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND, expecting ',' or ')' in C:\wamp\www\koding\index.php on line 18`

Comment: still won't work. isset() will return true, but it'll STILL be empty. you need to explicitly test against an empty string: `$_POST['clone-url'] !== ''`

Answer (score -1):

Your code doesn't check whether POST data has actually been received before it does validation on the input, so it's attempting to validate input that it hasn't actually received and therefore complaining about its absence. To solve this problem, wrap the PHP code at the top of the script thus:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  # your existing validation code goes here
};
```

This will cause the validation to occur only when there is input data to validate, and eliminate the spurious error you're seeing right now.

You may possibly also have trouble using an input field name with a hyphen in it; I don't see any immediate reason why it should fail, but it's not commonly done, and that may be the case because it doesn't work well. If, after making the above changes, you still have the same issue, try changing all instances of `clone-url` to `clone_url` and see what happens.

Comment: no. don't test for the presence/absence of a particular field to figure out a post has been done. There's the far far far more reliable `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'`. you might rename a field or tpyo[sic] it, but the $_SERVER value will always tell you how a request was made.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks! I didn't know about that; I'll update my answer to make reference to it.